# Problems with MeshFaceMaterial since revision 54 (Update 2)

Tags: three.js

Since I use revision 54 instead of revision 48 I get this excetption in my script:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined three.js:18155
bufferGuessUVType three.js:18155
initMeshBuffers three.js:17963
addObject three.js:21674
initWebGLObjects three.js:21608
render three.js:21145
...
THREE.JSONLoader.createModel three.js:9892
xhr.onreadystatechange
```

I am merging geometries with `THREE.GeometryUtils.merge`. Afterwards I use the merged geometry to construct a mesh. For this mesh I use `MeshFaceMaterial` to apply the materials of the faces. Since r54 this ends up in an exception. If I use some other material it works.. but then I can not use the materials of the original faces.

Update: All faces are pointing to a material `geometry.faces[i].materialIndex` but geometries do not contain a material array any more.

Update: 
I just want to merge geometries and keep their materials :) I thought this would be the solution but the `materialIndex` of a face will not be update on merge. I post this example to somehow explain what I need.

```
mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2,2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000}));
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2,2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000FF}));
mesh2.position.y = 3;
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(mergedGeo, mesh1);
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(mergedGeo, mesh2);
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([mesh1.material, mesh2.material])));
```

I could implement an own logic to link the merged faces to the right material but this is a bit frustrating since it worked in earlier versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As detailed in the [migration page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration)  since r52 it's now like this:

```
new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materialsArray ) );
```

EDIT: Before merging, you need to set the material index for each geometry

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.setMaterialIndex( mesh1.geometry, 0 );
THREE.GeometryUtils.setMaterialIndex( mesh2.geometry, 1 );
```

Comment: Wow! This changes improved the loading performance of my app very mutch! Thank you.